# npm prod build has pm-root go to root of AWS bucket not angular build file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've successfully run an Angular build to prod, then I've tried to drag and drop the files up to AWS. Everything gets copied, and IS there, but the index file gives 404 errors of not being able to find the compiles polyfill, style sheet and main ts files.

index.html routes/sources them to the local file, like so.

```
    <pm-root></pm-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.b7221955b56ca238a862.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.9c3f2c8c05f26e86793f.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.8cbda37452fab8baba0a.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.0a5aa62435a25eef6c98.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.4637c5bc4356d9dc116f.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.8695ecd18697495ae86e.js" nomodule></script></body>
    </html>
```

What is happening is, AWS is looking for these files in the root of the AWS S3 bucket, as opposed to the root folder of the files in which they are located. For example S3 > ang_apps > angBld1 > index.html

I upload these all at once. Any idea why AWS would do this? What is a workaround on this? I guess, I could manually edit the index.html file to go up two dirs. and reupload it, but that seems kind of silly for a build.
Does anyone else experience this and know of a reasonable solution?

Thanks.

Comment: anyone have any ideas or is this more of a question for the AWS community? Another thing, the build did not seem to include any ang modules with it...is that a red flag?

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if this is a Node/NPM issue, an AWS issue or an Angular issue but I was leaning toward the latter, maybe. I can run this build in prod mode, and then test it locally at port 4200, and it all works fine. I then upload it to AWS - specifically a folder or two deep within a bucket - and no matter how many folders deep I use the links are all relative to the bucket. Is this AWS at work? I wouldn't think so as the links are all local to the src build. Anyone have any insight into this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I do indeed have to create a specific bucket for a build, after it's done. I guess I don't understand why, but do understand that is the case. I didn't try altering the base href and pushing out the content via FTP to a different host, but that likely wouldn't work either?